Generic type that is extended gives error
type SignatureRecord = Record<string, (...args: any[]) => any>;

class CustomEventEmitter<K extends SignatureRecord> {
  emit<N extends keyof K>(name: N, ...args: Parameters<K[N]>): void {
  }
}

what this does is to receive an object (string: closure)
but when I write this:
class Emitter<M extends SignatureRecord> extends CustomEventEmitter<M> {}

type StatefulSignatures = {
  update: () => any;
};

class Stateful<M extends StatefulSignatures> extends Emitter<M> {
  protected triggerUpdate(): void {
    this.emit("update");
  }
}

type ComponentSignatures = StatefulSignatures & {
  mount: () => any;
};

class Component extends Stateful<ComponentSignatures> {
  protected triggerMount(): void {
    this.emit("mount");
  }
}

The emit from Stateful gives an error while the emit from Component works ok.
I get it's probably because in Stateful we use a generic type that is passed to Emitter while in Component we pass ComponentSignatures directly to Stateful.
How can I fix this?

...please don't give your classes the same name as builtin classes. Also, what is the point of worrying about type safety when your types are full of anys? Or is that just for the example?

@JaredSmith SignatureRecord is used as a type that restricts an object to have closure values, but the actual signatures of the closures are in K. For example, if we change to mount: (mounted: boolean) => any; when we call emit in Component, we see that it expects a mounted argument. And the any in closure => any is like that so in emit we can get the listener result, and if it's false we stop the next listeners from being called; that's implemented internally but I didn't think it was relevant to the question.

TS can't understand generic conditional types like Parameters<M["update"]> when M is generic.  (While you understand what Parameters means in general, TS does not. It can just evaluate it for specific type arguments.) If you really need to make that call you should widen this to Stateful<StatefulSignatures> first, as shown in this playground link. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer or find a suitable duplication target. If not, what am I missing?

@jcalz I couldn't have imagined that solution. It works pretty well. Now I have TS hints in both Stateful and Component with no problems. Thanks a lot.

I'll write an answer soon.

@jcalz sure, I'll accept it.

This is a design limitation of TypeScript. See microsoft/TypeScript#39222 for an authoritative answer.
The Parameters<T> utility type is a conditional type that, if you pass in a specific function type like () => any or (x: string, y: number) => boolean for T, will evaluate to the tuple of its parameter list, like [] or [x: string, y: number].  But TypeScript doesn't "understand" what it does in the abstract sense, for arbitrary types. So if T depends on a generic type parameter, like M in Parameters<M["update"]>, then TypeScript really has very little idea what that type might be.  It doesn't try to verify that, for example, [] will be assignable to it. Instead it just defers evaluation of it.
So when you call this.emit("update"), TypeScript compares the type of rest of the arguments after "update" (which is the empty tuple []) against the type Parameters<M["update"]>, and can't verify it. So you get an error.

If you want this code to work, I'd say that you need to work around it by widening from a generic type to its constraint.  Since M is constrained to StatefulSignatures, you can try widening this of type Stateful<M> to Stateful<StatefulSignatures>.  Once you do that, you can call emit("update"), since now the rest parameter is of type Parameters<StatefulSignatures["update"]> which is just []:
class Stateful<M extends StatefulSignatures> extends Emitter<M> {
    protected triggerUpdate(): void {        
        const _this: Stateful<StatefulSignatures> = this; // widen
        _this.emit("update"); // okay
    }
}

It's not always safe to widen generics to their constraint (it depends on the variance of the relevant type in its generics, see Difference between Variance, Covariance, Contravariance, Bivariance and Invariance in TypeScript). In this example it's allowed, but ultimately you might find that you need to do a type assertion to convince the compiler that what you're doing is safe (after you've convinced yourself, that is):
class Stateful<M extends StatefulSignatures> extends Emitter<M> {
    protected triggerUpdate(): void {
        (this as Stateful<StatefulSignatures>).emit("update");
    }
}

Playground link to code

Perfect. 2 key points here: (1) there's a limitation between generic types and Parameters and (2) you can use type assertion with this also. I had no idea of the latter. It's good to learn something new. Thank you, man.
